# Small changes in code aren't taken into account with OPCache enabled

Tags: php, apc, opcode, opcache, apcu

I've been using **APC** for **Opcode** optimization and data storage for few time until I read that `OPCache` is directly included in **PHP** since **PHP5.5**. Thus, I switched to **OPCache + APCu**.

But small changes in code like adding a '`die(var_dump($some_var));`' for debugging aren't taken into account but after some time.

Should I turn **OPCache** off in development mode ?

Comment: I would leave it on because OPCache is a piece of the production puzzle so you need to be able to detect OPCache issues in development. Try changing the frequency of validation in your development environment. http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.revalidate-freq

Answer (score 3):

If your using opcache then any changes to your code won't take effect if it's reading from cache. You can control how opcache behaves in your php.ini file (http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php).

If it takes a few seconds before your code changes appear and that's an problem for you, you can reduce the `opcache.revalidate_freq` to 0 so that file changes force it to re-cache instantly. I would advise you keep opcache on in production though as it will greatly increase the speed of your application.